# Printing Multiple labels in Zebra printer

Tags: zebra-printers

I am printing labels by concatenating the multiple zpl script in a string.
The labels are printing but the printer pauses for every print before printing another label.
The requirement is to print the labels continously.
Below is my script and suggest a solution

~CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW457
^LL0305
^LS0
^FO384,0^GFA,02560,02560,00008,:Z64:
eJxjYIADRgb8gJA8ITBq/qj5o+aPmj9q/qj5o+aPmj9q/iAAABheADQ=:0E2D
^BY3,3,63^FT21,248^BCN,,N,N
^FD>;0102570990000^FS
^FT171,165^A0N,20,19^FH^FDMade In: Nepal^FS
^FT19,131^A0N,20,19^FH^FDSize: No Size^FS
^FT171,131^A0N,20,19^FH^FDColor: Print/Pattern^FS
^FT19,165^A0N,20,19^FH^FD^FS
^FT72,286^A0N,23,24^FB258,1,0,C^FH^FDXXXXX^FS
^FT45,40^A0N,31,31^FB367,1,0,C^FH^FDXXXX ^FS
^FT45,78^A0N,31,31^FB367,1,0,C^FH^FD XXXX^FS
^FT450,184^A0B,31,31^FH^FD$99^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ~CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW457
^LL0305
^LS0
^FO384,0^GFA,02560,02560,00008,:Z64:
eJxjYIADRgb8gJA8ITBq/qj5o+aPmj9q/qj5o+aPmj9q/iAAABheADQ=:0E2D
^BY3,3,63^FT21,248^BCN,,N,N
^FD>;0102570990000^FS
^FT171,165^A0N,20,19^FH^FDMade In: Nepal^FS
^FT19,131^A0N,20,19^FH^FDSize: No Size^FS
^FT171,131^A0N,20,19^FH^FDColor: Print/Pattern^FS
^FT19,165^A0N,20,19^FH^FD^FS
^FT72,286^A0N,23,24^FB258,1,0,C^FH^FDYYY^FS
^FT45,40^A0N,31,31^FB367,1,0,C^FH^FDYYY ^FS
^FT45,78^A0N,31,31^FB367,1,0,C^FH^FD YYY^FS
^FT450,184^A0B,31,31^FH^FD$99^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ~CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW457
^LL0305
^LS0
^FO384,0^GFA,02560,02560,00008,:Z64:
eJxjYIADRgb8gJA8ITBq/qj5o+aPmj9q/qj5o+aPmj9q/iAAABheADQ=:0E2D
^BY3,3,63^FT21,248^BCN,,N,N
^FD>;0102570990000^FS
^FT171,165^A0N,20,19^FH^FDMade In: Nepal^FS
^FT19,131^A0N,20,19^FH^FDSize: No Size^FS
^FT171,131^A0N,20,19^FH^FDColor: Print/Pattern^FS
^FT19,165^A0N,20,19^FH^FD^FS
^FT72,286^A0N,23,24^FB258,1,0,C^FH^FDZZZ^FS
^FT45,40^A0N,31,31^FB367,1,0,C^FH^FDZZZ ^FS
^FT45,78^A0N,31,31^FB367,1,0,C^FH^FD ZZZ^FS
^FT450,184^A0B,31,31^FH^FD$99^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Thanks,
Alex Jones AX

I am printing labels by concatenating the multiple zpl script in a string.
The labels are printing but the printer pauses for every print before printing another label.
The requirement is to print the labels continuously.

I had tried these but no luck

^PQ2,0,1,Y,^XZ
^PQ2,0,1,N,^XZ

Answer (score 2):

Your format is putting the printer into tear-off mode using `^MMT`, causing the printer to pause after each label.  Try changing to `^MMR` (rewind mode).  That should eliminate the pause since the printer now assumes the labels are being spooled externally.

Comment: Thanks Mark.Still it is same. Now it is printing bit faster than before.

Comment: Is it still pausing after each label?  And did you replace each of the `^MMT`s in the three different label formats?

Comment: I replaced ^MMR in all 3 labels.Still, it is pausing before each print

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Mark Warren you also do not need the following line every time:

^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ

The ^JUS is saving settings each time which can slow print. You may want to make sure you send this the first time you connect to make sure the printer is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks Banno.I will try and update you

Comment: Thanks Banno!! It's working as expected, Issue is resolved.

Comment: glad to help - happy printing